# Programmatically save/convert image to webp format

Tags: android, image, bitmap, save, webp

Can bitmap be converted or saved to the **webp** format in android?

I search out for that but it turns out to be a dead end for me.

I need to save image to **webp** formate or else need to save in **PNG/JPEG** then convert to **webp** programmatically.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `CompressFormat.WEBP` to encode any bitmap in WEBP format.

Example:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path); 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 100, out);
out.close();
```

Comment: Does this have the same properties of webp file we convert using android studio?

Comment: No idea what properties you are talking about. Just give it a shot once.

Comment: Hi. Was the try worth?

Comment: How to replace EXIF data of JPEG/PNG to Webp image?

Comment: @hpAndro There is no direct way of changing EXIF data in Android SDK. You will need to do it manually by changing byte values. For that instead of directly compressing image to `FileOutputStream`, use an intermediate `ByteArrayOutputStream`, get the bytes and change the EXIF values.

Comment: @NabinBhandari it will work for .webp? because I am getting error like      Caused by: java.io.IOException: ExifInterface only supports saving attributes on JPEG formats. while featching from .webp file.

Comment: I'm not sure. You can give it a try, but it is extremely difficult.

Comment: how to convert gif to webp in android?

Comment: @tejshah If the GIF image has only one frame, decode the image to get a `Bitmap`. Then, compress the `Bitmap` in WEBP format.

Comment: @NabinBhandari thank for the replay. No my gif is more then 10 frame. any idea to do that?

Comment: You have 10 frames in gif. Do you want each frame to be saved as individual webp file or just want to convert gif into animated webp file?

Answer (score 3):

Since Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP is deprecated in Android 30, use as below

```
FileOutputStream(file).use { out ->
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
       bmp.compress(
       Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP_LOSSLESS, // or WEBP_LOSSY
       100,out)    
    } else {
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP,100,out)
    }
}
```